# How to use sed to extract negative number from a string

Tags: bash, sed

I need to extract a negative number from a file to another file, I already did this for a positive number, but I couldn't figure out how to do it for negative number.

```
sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+\.*[0-9]*).*?/\1/' bob.txt > outfile.txt
```

bob.txt content:

```
outputVoltage.u900 = Opaque: Float: 27.000000 V

outputVoltage.u900 = Opaque: Float: -27.000000 V
```

The above code works perfectly for the positive value and not the negative value.

Inside outfile, I suppose to have:

27.000000

-27.000000

Comment: Output second last column with awk: `awk '{print $(NF-1)}' file`

Comment: So just match the minus too? `([-]?[0-9]+....)` ?

Comment: Or remove everything else: `sed 's/..$//;s/.* //'`

Comment: Or `sed -E -e 's/.*Float: ([-0-9.]*) .*/\1/'`, but awk really is better suited for this.

Comment: `.*?` is a PCRE construct. sed does not support PCREs so whatever you're trying to do with that construct, sed is not doing that, it's doing something else (it's undefined behavior per POSIX so it could be doing anything but chances are it's ignoring the `?`).

Answer (score 2):

What about just print the fifth field:

```
awk '{print $5}' bob.txt
27.000000
-27.000000
```

Or search for a string and print it:

```
awk '/outputVoltage/{print $5}' bob.txt
27.000000
-27.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, instead of print,  I want to extract my result into another text file.

Comment: @Eniola that's not "instead of print" it's "in addition to print". Just add `> newfile` after the command, like you would any other command and you did for your existing sed command

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to `sed`, you're almost there, the correct command being

```
sed -r 's/.* (-?[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*).*?/\1/' bob.txt > outfile.txt
```

I've only added `-?` which matches zero or one `-` characters.